# Multiple dimensions problem in importing kml files

Tags: r, kml, dimensions

When I import multiple kml files into R by using `readOGR` in a loop, I came across the problem denotes as follows

> Error in ogrInfo(dsn = dsn, layer = layer, encoding = encoding,
>   use_iconv = use_iconv,  :  Multiple # dimensions: 2:3

Could anyone help me with this multiple dimensions problem?